# OpenType capital spacing (cpsp) in CSS without font-feature-settings?

Tags: css, typography, opentype, font-feature-settings

Is there a way to set capital spacing (`cpsp`) for an element without affecting other OpenType features applied to it?

Using `font-feature-settings` is not an option: e.g. `font-feature-settings: 'cpsp'` turns on capital spacing, but also *resets* all other OpenType features if they were in effect.

Some CSS properties allow for setting an OpenType tag without affecting others; e.g. `font-variant-numeric` for `onum`, `lnum` etc, or `font-variant-caps` for `smpc` and `c2sc`. But I don’t see a dedicated property for `cpsp` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think there currently isn't any CSS mechanism for this. I'm not sure why: it seems like it wouldn't have been hard to include a font-variant property for this. Maybe it was assumed that 'cpsp' is rarely used so not a priority.

Perhaps you can open an issue in the [csswg-drafts repo](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues) on GitHub suggesting this addition.